# Asp.Net Master Page View Model

Tags: asp.net, master-pages, viewmodel

I have an ASP.Net application that implements a Master Page and runs off a view model.

When I implement the model in my pages it works fine, but when I try to implement it in my Master Page it does not databind?

Here is a sample:

```
<li visible="<%# Model.TabVisible %>">
Misc Tab
</li>
```

So my question is why is this not databinding, and what event in the page Life Cycle should I call the Databind method manually? Page_Load does not do it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm an idiot. You need to have runat="server" inside the ListItem tag. I really need some sleep.